# Rails: Get related records having belonging to category having a particular enum attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In my rails app, I have `Organizations` and related posts belonging to the `Organization`.
`Organization` Model has a type attribute ie. enum
e.g. :gov, :edu, :sports etc.

```
enum sp_type: { gov: 0, edu: 1, sports: 2 }
```

I can get the list of Organization of type edu with

```
Organization.edu
```

I can get the posts by `Organization.edu.includes(:posts)`

I want to get all the posts belonging to the organizations of sp_type `edu`, what query should I perform to get the list of all the posts sorted by their `updated_at`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `type` is used for STI, so it's not very much recommended to use it as a column name.
2. The query (to get organizations):

   ```
   Organization.where(sp_type: Organization.sp_types[:edu]))
               .includes(:posts)
               .where.not(posts: { id: nil })
               .order('posts.updated_at')
   ```
3. The query to get posts:

   ```
   Post.joins(:organization)
       .where(organizations: { sp_type: Organization.sp_types[:edu]})
       .group('posts.id')
       .order('posts.updated_at')
   ```

Comment: I'm using sp_type attribute, since type is used for STI. edited question.

Comment: I have to add integer value e.g. `sp_type: 1` instead of `sp_type: :edu`is this the correct way to do it. I'm able to retrieve the posts.

Comment: @StarWars I edited for the conventional way to query enum column :)

Comment: @StarWars also, please make sure to accept the answers to your questions if they helper (I just noticed you rarely do that). P.S. nice nickname! :D

Comment: :) Do I have to do separate query to get list of organizations?

Comment: @StarWars no, I just wrote it and realized, I approached it from the wrong side :D Than added the correct one and was toolazy to remove the one you don't need